# Ajax / Header mismatch?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-webview

I'm hoping someone can answer this question for me, I'm not an expert on servers so please excuse me if I'm completely off base.

I'm using Android webview (PhoneGap 1.4.1) to make Ajax calls but I keep getting a ready state 4 status 0 on each call. I've spent the last couple hours investigating this and I may have figured out why. I used xhaus.com/headers to check my requests and found that in web view my "Accept" header is:

**text/xml, text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, text/plain, */*;q=0.8**

however, if I pull up the Android browser and check my header that way, I see that my "Accept" header is:

**application/xml, application/xhtml+xml, text/html;q=0.9, text/plain;q=0.8, image/png, */*;q=0.5**

I checked the server that is providing the XML and found that the return heads are "Content-Type" is set to:

**application/xml**

My first question is: Webview doesn't seem to support "application/xml" type, so could this be the reason I'm having my issue? Or am I completely off base here?

Second question: Is there anything I can do on the client side to fix this or will the server admin need to make the change? I am using GET to make the request.

Third question: Is this normal? why would web view / browser have this sort of mismatch?

My app has been tested on 10+ handsets and only 2 have this issue... Very strange.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but it sounds like you're calling a web service?  Some services support mutliple calling strategies depending on the content-type header that you pass.

For example SharePoint web services support both SOAP 1.0 (if Content-type is sent as "text/xml; charset=utf-8") and SOAP 1.2 (if Content-type is set as "application/soap+xml").

In your case I would try setting a content-type of "text/xml; charset=utf-8" and see what happens.

As for the "accept" header if the server response isn't acceptable based on the passed value it should pass a status of 406 (not acceptable).  It may simply be a bug in the server or in any of the steps between tho' that it's not.  Using a tool like Fiddler you should be able to recreate both requests (both variations on "accept") and see exactly what the server responses with however - that may be the easiest way to truly get to the bottom of things.